Use Hölder's inequality when $\int f_ngd\mu$ is bounded
In a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$, say that $1<p,q<\infty$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e., $f_n\in L^p$ for all $n$, and for each $g\in L^q$ $$\sup_n \left|\int f_n g d\mu\right|<\infty.$$
Show that $f\in L^p$.
Now, I realize I need to use Hölder's inequality, but I am not quite sure of how to get the result.

Shouldn't this somehow follow from (a variant of) the dominated convergence theorem?

It is helpful to note that a weakly bounded set in a Banach space is norm bounded

@leoli1 were you hinting at using the uniform boundedness principle, or you have a different approach from kobe's?

Yes, that is how you show that statement above

Consider the continuous linear functionals $T_n$ on $L^q$ given by $T_n(g) = \int_X f_n g\, d\mu$. By hypothesis, $\{T_n\}$ is pointwise bounded, so by the uniform boundedness principle, $\sup_n \|T_n\| =: M < \infty$. Note $\|T_n\| = \|f_n\|_p$, so $\|f_n\|_p \le M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Use Fatou's lemma to deduce $\|f\|_p \le M$.

Thanks @kobe that's very neat. I have a question: I see that $|T_n| \leq |f_n|_p$, but why should that be an equality?

Hello @DavideLeonessi, suppose WLOG that $|f_n|_p \neq 0$ and set $g = |f_n|^{-p/q} |f_n|^{p-1}\operatorname{sign}(f_n)$. Then $|g|^q = |f_n|^p |f_n|_p^{-p}$ and $f_n g = |f_n|^p |f_n|p^{-p/q}$. Thus $|g|{q} = 1$ and $$\int_X f_n g, d\mu = |f_n|_p^{-p/q} \int_X |f_n|^p, d\mu = |f_n|_p^{-p/q}|f_n|_p^p = |f_n|p$$ Therefore $|T_n| \ge |T_n(g)| = |f_n|{p}$ as desired.

I see, that's great, thank you very much!
